# If $\zeta$ is a singularity of $g$ and $\eta$ is not then $-res\left(\frac{g}{z-\eta},\zeta\right)$ is the principal part of $g$ at $\zeta $

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $\zeta$
  is a pole or essential singularity of $g$
  and $\eta$
  is not a singularity of $g$
 , I want to show that $-\text{Res}\left(\frac{g}{z-\eta},\zeta\right)$
  is equal to the principal part of $g$
  at $\zeta$ evaluated at $\eta$.

I started by simplifying the problem by WLOG assuming $\zeta=0$
 . The function $\frac{1}{z-\eta}$
  is holomorphic in a small enough neighborhood of $0$
  and has a Taylor series there given by $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\eta^{n+1}}z^{n}$
 . I thought about proceeding by simply directly finding the Laurent series of $\frac{g}{z-\eta}$
  at $0$
  but finding the coefficients as a convolution of the coefficients of both series is only possible in the case of a pole and even then it's not particularly pretty.

I'd really appreciate some help in the form of a nice thick hint :)

Sidenote: I couldn't get the title under 150 characters while writing $-\text{res}\left(\frac{g}{z-\eta},\zeta\right)$ If someone wants to rephrase to fix it go ahead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\zeta$ is an isolated singularity of $g$, and $g$ is holomorphic in the annulus $K=\{ z : 0 < \lvert z-\zeta\rvert < R\}$, then the integral formula says that for every $\eta \in K$ we have

$$g(\eta) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\lvert z-\zeta\rvert = a} \frac{g(z)}{z-\eta}\,dz - \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\lvert z-\zeta\rvert = b} \frac{g(z)}{z-\eta}\,dz,$$

for all $a,b$ with $0 < b < \lvert \eta-\zeta\rvert < a < R$. On the one hand, by the definition of a residue,

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\lvert z-\zeta\rvert = b} \frac{g(z)}{z-\eta}\,dz = \operatorname{Res}\left(\frac{g(z)}{z-\eta};\zeta\right).$$

On the other, that integral is by definition the principal part of $g$ evaluated in $\eta$.

Comment: Deleted my previous comment as it was irrelevant. 
I see now why the principal part of $g$ evaluated at $\eta$ is equal to that integral. I'm not sure I understood in which part you actually needed the entire integral formula and not just the second integral though?

Comment: The entire integral formula is not _needed_, but it shows where things come from. $$g(\eta) = \underbrace{\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\lvert z-\zeta\rvert = a} \frac{g(z)}{z-\eta}\,dz}_{\text{secondary part}}\; \underbrace{-\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\lvert z-\zeta\rvert = b} \frac{g(z)}{z-\eta}\,dz}_{\text{principal part}}$$